# Getting the last n elements of a vector. Is there a better way than using the length() function?

Tags: python, r, indexing

If, for argument's sake, I want the last five elements of a 10-length vector in Python, I can use the `-` operator in the range index like so:

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x[-5:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

What is the best way to do this in R? Is there a cleaner way than my current technique, which is to use the `length()` function?

```
> x <- 0:9
> x
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> x[(length(x) - 4):length(x)]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9
>
```

The question is related to time series analysis btw where it is often useful to work only on recent data.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

see `?tail` and `?head` for some convenient functions:

```
> x <- 1:10
> tail(x,5)
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

For the argument's sake : everything but the last five elements would be :

```
> head(x,n=-5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

As @Martin Morgan says in the comments, there are two other possibilities which are faster than the tail solution, in case you have to carry this out a million times on a vector of 100 million values. For readibility, I'd go with tail.

```
test                                        elapsed    relative 
tail(x, 5)                                    38.70     5.724852     
x[length(x) - (4:0)]                           6.76     1.000000     
x[seq.int(to = length(x), length.out = 5)]     7.53     1.113905
```

benchmarking code :

```
require(rbenchmark)
x <- 1:1e8
do.call(
  benchmark,
  c(list(
    expression(tail(x,5)),
    expression(x[seq.int(to=length(x), length.out=5)]),
    expression(x[length(x)-(4:0)])
  ),  replications=1e6)
)
```

Comment: But not faster than slicing - testing bears this out.

Comment: Thanks Nick interesting. Yeah Python slicing is a nice feature of the language.

Comment: @Nick : Indeed. On a vector of length 1e6 and 1000 replications, it is about 0.3 seconds slower. Imagine what you can do with the 0.3 seconds you saved...

Comment: The implementation of utils:::tail.default is `x[seq.int(to=length(x), length.out=5)]` which seems to be about 10x faster than `tail()` but without the sanity checks; `x[length(x)-(4:0)]` is faster still.

Comment: @Joris: I can imagine what I'd do with them after I ran that particular operation in an inner loop a billion times.. :-)  The point is that slicing is not any less clear, but more optimal, so in general I'd go that route.

Answer (score 9):

The disapproval of `tail` here based on speed alone doesn't really seem to emphasize that part of the slower speed comes from the fact that tail is safer to work with, if you don't for sure that the length of x will exceed `n`, the number of elements you want to subset out:

```
x <- 1:10
tail(x, 20)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
x[length(x) - (0:19)]
#Error in x[length(x) - (0:19)] : 
#  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Tail will simply return the max number of elements instead of generating an error, so you don't need to do any error checking yourself.  A great reason to use it.  Safer cleaner code, if extra microseconds/milliseconds don't matter much to you in its use.

Answer (score 5):

You can do exactly the same thing in R with two more characters:

```
x <- 0:9
x[-5:-1]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9
```

or

```
x[-(1:5)]
```

Comment: What if I don't know the length of the Vector, but I always still want the last 5 element? The python version still works but your R example returns the last 15 elements and so would still require a call to length()?

Comment: Sacha, I don't think your answer generalises.  What your code example does is to drop the first 5 results, rather than keeping the last five.  In this example it's the same thing, but the following doesn't work:  `x <- 0:20; x[-5:-1]` - this returns the last fifteen elements.

Comment: I don't know python, but in the OP's `x[-5:]`: does this mean skip the first 5 elements, or keep the last 5? If it the first one, he is indirectly using your length, like you are, here (otherwise, how do you know which elements to skip?)

Comment: the "-" operator in Python means count backwards. So it'll always return the last 5 elements in this case.

Comment: Ah right, I don't know python and assumed it meant skip the first 5. `tail`  is what you want then.

Answer (score 5):

How about `rev(x)[1:5]`?

```
x<-1:10
system.time(replicate(10e6,tail(x,5)))
 user  system elapsed 
 138.85    0.26  139.28 

system.time(replicate(10e6,rev(x)[1:5]))
 user  system elapsed 
 61.97    0.25   62.23
```

Comment: Late comment. The processing time taken reversing the vector is too large for long vectors. Try timing it when `x <- 1:10e6`

Comment: Good point @ChrisNjuguna. Works great using a vector of length 10 though :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function to do it and seems reasonably fast.

```r
endv <- function(vec,val) {
 if(val > length(vec)) {
  stop("Length of value greater than length of vector")
 } else {
  vec[((length(vec) - val) + 1):length(vec)]
 }
}
```

USAGE:

```r
test <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,NA,1,1)
endv(test,5)
endv(LETTERS,5)
```

BENCHMARK:

```
                                                        test replications elapsed relative
    1                                 expression(tail(x, 5))       100000    5.24    6.469
    2 expression(x[seq.int(to = length(x), length.out = 5)])       100000    0.98    1.210
    3                       expression(x[length(x) - (4:0)])       100000    0.81    1.000
    4                                 expression(endv(x, 5))       100000    1.37    1.691
```

Answer (score 3):

I just add here something related. I was wanted to access a vector with backend indices, ie writting something like `tail(x, i)` but to return `x[length(x) - i + 1]` and not the whole tail.

Following commentaries I benchmarked two solutions:

```
accessRevTail <- function(x, n) {
    tail(x,n)[1]
}

accessRevLen <- function(x, n) {
  x[length(x) - n + 1]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(accessRevLen(1:100, 87), accessRevTail(1:100, 87))
Unit: microseconds
                     expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
  accessRevLen(1:100, 87)  1.860  2.3775  2.84976  2.803  3.2740   6.755   100
 accessRevTail(1:100, 87) 22.214 23.5295 28.54027 25.112 28.4705 110.833   100
```

So it appears in this case that even for small vectors, `tail` is very slow comparing to direct access