# R: It is possible to modify "[" and "[[" to introduce Python-like negative indexing?

Tags: r, subset

I want an easy way to access the last values of objects. I have implemented a function that allows for Python-like negative indexing (count-backwards-and-keep-only-those-elements instead of R's remove-those-elements-and-keep-all-other-elements). There are some questions about this, but no one attempted to do this:

- [How to access the last value in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434/how-to-access-the-last-value-in-a-vector)
- [Getting the last n elements of a vector. Is there a better way than using the length() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136613/getting-the-last-n-elements-of-a-vector-is-there-a-better-way-than-using-the-le)

Basically, I want to redefine `[` and `[[`, so that one can user a special operator (e.g. `_`) to use Python-like indexing. For instance, like this:

```
iris[1, ] #first row
iris[-1, ] #everything but first row
iris[_1, ] #last row, equivalent to tail(iris, 1)
iris[, _1] #last column, equivalent to iris[ncol(iris)]
```

Is it possible? I know it is possible to redefine e.g. `+` to introduce character concatenation like other languages have ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18175871/3980197)).

In case it's not possible, here's my workaround function:

```
extract_last = function(x, margin_1, margin_2, drop = FALSE) {
  #check types
  if (!(is.vector(x) || is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x))) stop("x was an unsupported type (not a vector, matrix or data.frame)!")

  #vector
  if (is.vector(x)) return(rev(x)[margin_1])

  #get dims
  x_dims = dim(x)

  #make indices
  if (missing("margin_1")) {
    margin_1 = 1:x_dims[1]
  } else {
    margin_1 = (x_dims[1] + 1) - margin_1
  }
  if (missing("margin_2")) {
    margin_2 = 1:x_dims[2]
  } else {
    margin_2 = (x_dims[2] + 1) - margin_2
  }

  #subset
  return(x[margin_1, margin_2, drop = drop])
}

#tests
extract_last(iris, 1) == tail(iris, 1)
extract_last(iris, 10:1) == tail(iris, 10)
extract_last(iris, , 1) == iris[5]
extract_last(iris, , 2:1) == iris[4:5]
extract_last(iris, 10:1, 1) == iris[141:150, 5, drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Is `iris[nrow(iris), ]` or `iris[, ncol(iris)]` too much typing?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in general (i.e., not only for a specific class). E.g., you can't really define `[` methods for the implicit classes (`character` , `numeric`, ...).

Comment: You could write a function called \`[\` (see [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) written by Hadley Wickam), but I wouldn't advise it for so many reasons. I'd argue the easiest solution is `T <- function(...){a <- list(...); do.call(tail,a)}`.. this is pretty short and does your stuff: `a <- matrix(1:9,3,3); T(a[1,],1); T(a,1)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That only works for the very last element. I want to be able to use Python-like syntax as stated in the question. For instance, `extract_last(iris, c(20, 15, 5, 1))` which is equivalent to `iris[(nrow(iris)+1) - c(20, 15, 5, 1), ]`.

Comment: @Laterow I read the book but could not figure out a way to change the `[` function in the same way that I've changed `+` (see the answer linked to in the question).

Comment: By using backticks  `\`[\``. So something like `\`[\` <- function(x,y,z=NULL){if (!is.null(z)){print("this was a bad idea")} else {do.call(.Primitive("["),list(x,y))}}; b <- 1:10; b[3]; b[2,3]`. [And in case you can't figure it out, use `rm(\`[\`)` to get rid of it again.]

Comment: I agree that it would be kinda cool if `R` added a keyword like, say, "last" so that `foo[1:(last-5)]` would skip the last 5 elements, but in the long run it's really not that hard to use `ncol` or `nrow` as Roman suggested.  If you're going to be accessing the same array a lot, just define a couple variables `nrowmat <- nrow(mat)` and use them.

Comment: It does not suffice in general. That approach only works when one wants the last element. What if I want the last 10 elements? It quickly gets cumbersome. It is easy with the function I gave above, see e.g. the last example.