# Use strsplit to get last character in r

Tags: regex, r, string, parsing, strsplit

I have a file of baby names that I am reading in and then trying to get the last character in the baby name.  For example, the file looks like..

```
Name      Sex 
Anna      F
Michael   M
David     M
Sarah     F
```

I read this in using

```
sourcenames = read.csv("babynames.txt", header=F, sep=",")
```

I ultimately want to end up with my result looking like..

```
Name   Last Initial   Sex
Michael  l             M
Sarah    h             F
```

I've managed to split the name into separate characters..

```
sourceout = strsplit(as.character(sourcenames$Name),'')
```

But now where I'm stuck is how to get the last letter, so in the case of Michael, how to get 'l'.  I thought tail() might work but its returning the last few records, not the last character in each Name element.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: There is an answer for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434/how-to-access-the-last-value-in-a-vector

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r) suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For your `strsplit` method to work, you can use `tail` with `sapply`

```
df$LastInit <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Name), ""), tail, 1)
df
#      Name Sex LastInit
# 1    Anna   F        a
# 2 Michael   M        l
# 3   David   M        d
# 4   Sarah   F        h
```

Alternatively, you can use `substring`

```
with(df, substring(Name, nchar(Name)))
# [1] "a" "l" "d" "h"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works a treat.  Can I ask how the tail part is working in the sapply, like which parameters of sapply() is it I'm passing tail and the value 1 into.  I'm really new to R so apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: Sure.  You're applying `tail` iteratively through the `strsplit` list, taking the `1`st element of the tail-end of each vector.  The `1` is telling `tail` how many elements to take.  The default is six, which is what you were probably getting

Answer (score 7):

Try this function from `stringi` package:

```
require(stringi)
x <- c("Ala", "Sarah","Meg")
stri_sub(x, from = -1, to = -1)
```

This function extracts substrings between from and to index. If indexes are negative, then it counts characters from the end of a string. So if `from=-1` and `to=-1` it means that we want substring from last to last character :)

Why use `stringi`? Just look at this benchmarks :)

```
require(microbenchmark)
x <- sample(x,1000,T)
microbenchmark(stri_sub(x,-1), str_extract(x, "[a-z]{1}$"), gsub(".*(.)$", "\\1", x), 
                    sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ""), tail, 1), substring(x, nchar(x)))

Unit: microseconds
                                           expr       min         lq     median         uq       max neval
                                stri_sub(x, -1)    56.378    63.4295    80.6325    85.4170   139.158   100
                    str_extract(x, "[a-z]{1}$")   718.579   764.4660   821.6320   863.5485  1128.715   100
                     gsub(".*(.)$", "\\\\1", x)   478.676   493.4250   509.9275   533.8135   673.233   100
 sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ""), tail, 1) 12165.470 13188.6430 14215.1970 14771.4800 21723.832   100
                         substring(x, nchar(x))   133.857   135.9355   141.2770   147.1830   283.153   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using data.table (for relatively clean syntax) and stringr (easier grammar).

```
library(data.table); library(stringr)

df = read.table(text="Name      Sex 
Anna      F
Michael   M
David     M
Sarah     F", header=T)
setDT(df) # convert to data.table

df[, "Last Initial" := str_extract(Name, "[a-z]{1}$") ][]

          Name Sex Last Initial
    1:    Anna   F            a
    2: Michael   M            l
    3:   David   M            d
    4:   Sarah   F            h
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
x <- c("abc","123","Male")
regmatches(x,regexpr(".$", x))
## [1] "c" "3" "e"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one... str_sub() function in stringr package would help you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(babynames)
babynames %>%
  select(name,sex) %>%
  mutate(last_letter = str_sub(name,-1,-1)) %>%
  head()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a Regular Expression and `gsub`:

```
sourcenames$last.letter = gsub(".*(.)$", "\\1", sourcenames$Name)

sourcenames

     Name Sex last.letter
1    Anna   F           a
2 Michael   M           l
3   David   M           d
4   Sarah   F           h
```

Comment: Ok use this. `regex` blows `substr` method out of the water. 2x the speed :-( `unlist(Map(function(x) substring(x, nchar(x)), sourcenames$Name))`

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` approach:

```
sourcenames %>% rowwise() %>% mutate("Last Initial" = strsplit(as.character(Name),'') %>% unlist() %>% .[length(.)])
```