# Tail function on factor in R

Tags: r

I have seen this post ([How to access the last value in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434/how-to-access-the-last-value-in-a-vector)) showing how to use the tail function. When I apply tail to a factor, it returns all the levels of the factor, including the last factor to appear. Example:

```
x = rep(1:4, 6)
y =  rnorm(4*length(x), 0, 0.1)

d = data.frame(ERF=x, y)

d$ERF = factor(d$ERF)

a <- tail(d$ERF, n=1)

> a
[1] 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

I just want to store the last factor as a variable (a). I can see that a[1] is 4 but:

```
> a[1]
[1] 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

I looked at `?tail` but cant seem to figure it out. I know it must be simple I just need a nudge in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: use `droplevels` i.e. `droplevels(a)` or call `factor` again i.e. `factor(a)` to get only the levels that are present in `a` and remove the unused levels.

Comment: oh thank you, so I can now store it as a variable. ..Cant seem to select your comment as an answer.

Comment: No problem.  It is because I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry @akrun I didn't see that you already posted this as a comment. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thank you. I promise I didn't copy ;)

Comment: @RHertel convfess !! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tail`, like any indexing function, returns *elements*. However, an element of a factor is still a factor, so when you print it all the factor levels are printed.

Nevertheless, you can use that value as any other value. If you want to use the value itself, transform it into a character string via `as.character`.

If you want to get rid of all unused factor levels, use `droplevels`:

```
f = factor(letters)

tail(f)
# [1] u v w x y z
# Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

as.character(tail(f))
# [1] "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

droplevels(tail(f))
# [1] u v w x y z
# Levels: u v w x y z
```

Comment: Just a small comment, the `factor` levels not only printed, but they are actually stored there too as `attributes(tail(f))` will reveal.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `factor(a)`

```
> a
[1] 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4
> factor(a)
[1] 4
Levels: 4
```