# Accessing a vector element by name in R when some names are duplicated

Tags: r, vector

I had the vector  `x<-1:5` I named its elements (wrongly) `names(x)<-rep(c(letters[1:4], "a"))`. How can I access the *last* element by name?
`x["a"]` only return the first element named `"a"`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434/how-to-access-the-last-value-in-a-vector?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
x[names(x) == "a"]
# a a 
# 1 5
```

Or to get only the final one:

```
x[tail(which(names(x) == "a"), 1L)]
# a 
# 5
```

This is more readable but marginally slower than getting at what `tail` does directly (see `getAnywhere("tail.default")`):

```
x[(idx <- which(names(x) == "a"))[length(idx)]
# a 
# 5
```

Comment: You could add an info about `tail` to get the last element which I find easier. (And on a side note, it would also work without the `which`)

Comment: I would actually use `tail(x[names(x) == "a"], 1)` but it's personal preference of course

Answer (score 1):

The function duplicated() will give a boolean vector of occurrences except the first. In your case it would be only the second "a". Consequently,

```
x[duplicated(names(x))]
```

would give you the second entry. If you add more "a"-entries to the dataframe, you would get a vector of 2,3 and so on elements. All except the first. In that case you would have to cycle through or something.

Comment: I think this approach is misleading for the problem at hand. I happens to work for this minimal example but could be completely wrong for "real world" data.

Comment: Why is it less robust than the other solution? I can also throw a head() or tail() at this.

Comment: It's not "robust" a) because you don't reference the name `a` which is asked for - this means that if any other name, e.g. `b` was also duplicated, those would also be returned, and b) they want to access only the last element while your approach would return all except the first occurence - which only happens to work because there are exactly two occurences of `a` in `x`. Consider: `x <- 1:10; names(x) <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE)`

Comment: a) is true I overlooked that

Comment: Also note that it would need to be written as `x[duplicated(names(x))]`, i.e. `()`instead of `[]`