# Given a list, how do I access the last value of each elements with different sizes

Tags: r, list

I have a list of character vectors, and I would like to access the last value of each element.

```
mylist<-list(A=c("a"),
             B=c("a","b"),
             C=c("a","b","c"),
             D=c("a","b","c","d"))
```

At first, (by looking at some related threads in Python), I thought I could do something like:

```
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
   print(mylist[[i]][-1])
}
# character(0)
# [1] "b"
# [1] "b" "c"
# [1] "b" "c" "d"
```

I guess this doesn't work. Basically, as a result, I would like

```
myfunction<-function(mylist){
  output<-as.character()
  for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  output<-c(output, mylist[[i]][length(mylist[[i]])])}
  return(output)
}

myfunction(mylist)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: `sapply(mylist, function(l) l[length(l)])`

Comment: or `sapply(mylist, tail, 1)`

Comment: or `mapply("[", mylist, lengths(mylist))`, which is dumb

Comment: or `unlist(mylist)[cumsum(lengths(mylist))]`, which is kinda fun

Comment: or `vapply(mylist, tail, character(1), 1)`(might be faster)

Comment: `vapply` is faster than `sapply` but `tail` is slower than `x[[length(x)]]` and I believe it will be the bottleneck. I'm betting on the solution that @Rich calls dumb but it would be nice if @Markus could add a benchmark to his answer.

Comment: benchmark on accessing the last element of a vector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37238415/2270475

Comment: FYI see benchmark in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rich Scriven pointed out in the (deleted) comments there are many ways to accomplish this task, one of which is to use `sapply` and `tail` with argument `n = 1`:

```
sapply(mylist, tail, n = 1)
#  A   B   C   D 
#"a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Another, [safer and potentially faster variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339650/why-is-vapply-safer-than-sapply) of the same idea is to use `vapply`

```
vapply(mylist, tail, FUN.VALUE = character(1), n = 1)
# or a little shorter
# vapply(mylist, tail, "", 1)
```

---

(another) **benchmarking**

```
set.seed(1)
mylist <- replicate(1e5, list(sample(letters, size = runif(1, 1, length(letters)))))

benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = {myfunction(mylist)},
  f2 = {sapply(mylist, function(l) l[length(l)])},
  f3 = {vapply(mylist, function(l) l[length(l)], "")},
  f4 = {sapply(mylist, tail, 1)},
  f5 = {vapply(mylist, tail, "", 1)},
  f6 = {mapply("[", mylist, lengths(mylist))},
  f7 = {mapply("[[", mylist, lengths(mylist))}, # added this out of curiosity
  f8 = {unlist(mylist)[cumsum(lengths(mylist))]},
  times = 100L
)

autoplot(benchmark)
```

Same result here: Rich's `unlist(mylist)[cumsum(lengths(mylist_long))]` is the fastest by far. No real difference between `sapply` and `vapply` it seems. `myfunction()` as defined in OP's question.

[image]

```
#benchmark
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr         min          lq        mean     median          uq        max neval
#   f1 28797.26121 30462.16785 31836.26875 31191.7762 32950.92537 36586.5477   100
#   f2   106.34213   117.75074   127.97763   124.9191   134.82047   176.2058   100
#   f3    99.72042   106.87308   119.59811   113.9663   123.63619   465.5335   100
#   f4  1242.11950  1291.38411  1409.35750  1350.3460  1505.76089  1880.6537   100
#   f5  1189.22615  1274.48390  1366.07234  1333.8885  1418.75394  1942.2803   100
#   f6   112.27316   123.73429   132.39888   129.8220   138.33851   191.2509   100
#   f7   107.27392   118.19201   128.06681   123.1317   133.29827   208.8425   100
#   f8    28.03948    28.84125    31.19637    30.3115    32.94077    40.9624   100
```

Comment: Amazing. Never use `myfunction()`

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking the solutions proposed in the comments we find that Rich's proposal using `unlist` is the fastest.

By inspecting the code and tweaking the parameters we can make it even faster.

The slowness of `tail` is discussed there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37238415/2270475

On OP's sample data:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  r2evans = sapply(mylist, function(l) l[length(l)]),
  markus  = sapply(mylist, tail, 1),
  Rich1   = mapply("[", mylist, lengths(mylist)),
  Rich2   = unlist(mylist)[cumsum(lengths(mylist))],
  markus2 = vapply(mylist, tail, character(1), 1),
  mm      = .Internal(unlist(mylist,FALSE,FALSE))[cumsum(lengths(mylist,FALSE))],
  unit = "relative"
)
# Unit: relative
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq         max neval
#  r2evans 16.083333 12.764706 25.545957 12.368421 13.133333 122.1428571   100
#   markus 82.333333 59.294118 50.937673 60.342105 60.644444  10.2253968   100
#    Rich1 19.583333 15.294118 13.368047 15.394737 15.622222   2.7492063   100
#    Rich2  4.166667  3.705882  3.211045  3.789474  3.911111   0.7650794   100
#  markus2 73.166667 53.176471 44.669822 50.263158 54.155556  10.4857143   100
#       mm  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   1.0000000   100
```

On a 1000 times longer list:

```
mylist_long <- do.call(c,replicate(1000,mylist,simplify = F))
length(mylist_long) # [1] 4000

microbenchmark(
  r2evans = sapply(mylist_long, function(l) l[length(l)]),
  markus  = sapply(mylist_long, tail, 1),
  Rich1   = mapply("[", mylist_long, lengths(mylist_long)),
  Rich2   = unlist(mylist_long)[cumsum(lengths(mylist_long))],
  markus2 = vapply(mylist_long, tail, character(1), 1),
  mm      = .Internal(unlist(mylist_long,FALSE,FALSE))[cumsum(lengths(mylist_long,FALSE))],
  unit = "relative"
)
# Unit: relative
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  r2evans  26.14882  27.20436  27.07436  28.13731  28.54701  27.23846   100
#   markus 679.57251 698.84828 668.00160 715.30180 674.71067 443.42502   100
#    Rich1  27.53607  28.80581  29.82736  29.00353  31.02343  38.79978   100
#    Rich2  22.39863  21.79129  20.41467  21.53371  20.70750  13.03032   100
#  markus2 667.97494 702.14882 676.91881 718.41899 696.11934 633.17181   100
#       mm   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   100
```

Comment: Wow, I never win those!

Comment: It really surprised me that `unlist` wins against `mappy`, I thought it was a heavy operation but it seems it's really not.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Just saw your comment about the benchmark and did my own. No surprises however, given your results.