# Extract lines from a list

Tags: r

When I try to grep the last line of this list, R returns all the lines in the list, is there a way to make R only grep the last line in this example?

```r
stringlines<-as.list(c("Total des actifs immobilisés 350 952","Total des actifs non courants 357 268",
               "Total des actifs courants 4 324 646",
               "Total des actifs 4 682 115"))
  
  
stringlines[grep("Total des actifs",stringlines,fixed = T)]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Total des actifs immobilisés 350 952"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Total des actifs non courants 357 268"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Total des actifs courants 4 324 646"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "Total des actifs 4 682 115"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0.9002)</sup>

Comment: why do you have `as.list`? You cannot `grep` on a list but rather on a vector

Comment: the data I have is in this format

Comment: `stringlines[grep("Total des actifs",stringlines,fixed = T)][length(stringlines[grep("Total des actifs",stringlines,fixed = T)])]`

Comment: @Yuriy Saraykin thank you, it works just fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the last value in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77434/how-to-access-the-last-value-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have a larger file and only want the entries that contain "Total des actifs" followed by numbers and spaces you can use:

`stringlines[grep("^Total des actifs [0-9 ]*$", stringlines)]`